# How do I solve Double NAT?

Tags: networking, router, internet, nat

I have a Web Server running on my Computer. I can reach it through my LAN but not reachable from the Internet or WAN. Later I checked what was the issue and Found that my router's IP is a private IP address. So I guess my router is running behind another router or device which is blocking incoming traffic.

I need to tell that router to forward incoming traffic to my routers address. How do I solve this problem? (Is this called Double NAT?)

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: You need to ask the administrator of that router to forward incoming traffic. Depending on who that is, what you want might or might not be possible.

Comment: Your ISP is likely using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...